# Possibilities to get a column which takes only numbers with leading zeroes

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

I've got a RadGridView.

In it I have column

```
        GridViewDecimalColumn decColumn= new GridViewDecimalColumn();
        decColumn.Name = "Deccolumn";
        decColumn.HeaderText = Resources.Messages.ClientColumn;
        decColumn.FieldName = "Dec";
        decColumn.MinWidth = 80;
        decColumn.FormatString = "{0:00000}";
        decColumn.DecimalPlaces = 0;
        TableGridView.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(decColumn);
```

Now what I try to achieve is that inside this column I can put in numbers from 0-99999999 with the program filling up (if not already typed in by me) the number with leading 0s so that the Maximum number of Digits is shown.
thus 8 would become 00000008. Additionally only numbers should be allowed.

With a TextBox column I managed to achieve this but the Manual "is it only a number" check is a bit tendious. Thus I wanted to go with the decimal column but here the Problem is the typical no leading 0s Problem.

so my question here is: Is there any way to let it accept leading zeroes or any other way to define a column like I Need it without overriding a few Events manually?